# Managing multiple anylogic simulations within an experiment

Tags: anylogic

We are developing an ABM under AnyLogic 7 and are at the point where we want to make multiple simulations from a single experiment. Different parameters are to be set for each simulation run so as to generate results for a small suite of standard scenarios.

We have an experiment that auto-starts without the need to press the "Run". Subsequent pressing of the Run does increment the experiment counter and reruns the model.

What we'd like is a way to have the auto-run, or single press of Run, launch a loop of simulations. Within that loop would be the programmatic adjustment of the variables linked to passed parameters.

EDIT-  One wrinkle is that some parameters are strings. The Optimization or Parameter Variation experiments don't lend themselves to enumerating a set of strings to be be used across a set of simulation runs. You can set *a* string per parameter for all the simulation runs within one experiment.

We've used the help sample for "Running a Model from Outside Without Presentation Window", to add the auto-run capability to the initial experiment setup block of code. A method to wait for Run 0 to complete, then dispatch Run 1, 2, etc, is needed.

Pointers to tutorial models with such features, or to a snip of code for the experiment's java blocks are much appreciated.

Comment: As Benjamin said, are you aware of the built-in 'multi-run' AnyLogic experiment types. Just see Experiment Framework in the help. You suggest that you're running the model externally, but I don't think that makes any difference; you can run a Parameter Variation experiment externally in the same way as a normal Simulation one.

Answer (score 2):

maybe I don't understand your need but this certainly sounds like you'd want to use a "Parameter Variation" experiment. You can specify which parameters should be varied in which steps and running the experiment automatically starts as many simulation runs as needed, all without animation.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will review the help pointers, again. We're already using Optimization for some calibration. As a software engineer trying to wrestle some explicit control within the AnyLogic IDE, I'm looking for control with the JAVA Actions blocks rather than the prepackaged experiment options. This ABM is part of a larger integrated assessment model, and more explicit model control would greatly simplify the integration process.

Comment: What you might be after, then, is a `CustomExperiment`. Using it, you get full programmatic control over when / where / how the model starts, how it runs, how many times it runs, etc. It's tricky to get the hang of, though, so if you use it -- and if it works for you -- don't forget to tell the rest of us how you did it! :D

Answer (score 2):

As you, I was confronted to this  problem. 
My aim was to use parameter variation with a model and variation were on non numeric data, and I knew the number of runs to start.
Then i succeed in this task with the help of Custom Variation.

- Firstly I build an experiment typed as 'multiple run', create my GUI (user was able to select the string values used in each run.
- Then, I create a new java class which inherit from the previous 'multiple run' experiment,

In this class (called MyMultipleRunClass) was present:
- overload of the getMaximumIterations method from default experiment to provide to default anylogic callback the correct number of iteration, and idnex was also used to retrieve my parameter value from array,
- implementation of the static method start,

```
public static void start() {
    prepareBeforeExperimentStart_xjal( MyMultipleRunClass.class);
    MyMultipleRunClass ex = new MyMultipleRunClass();
    ex.setCommandLuneArguments_xjal(null);
    ex.setup(null);
}
```

Then the experiment to run is the 'empty' customExperiment, which automatically start the other Multiple run experiment thru the presented subclass.
Maybe it exists shortest path, but from my point of view anylogic is correctly used (no trick with non exposed interface) and it works as expected.