# AnyLogic non-interactive mode

Tags: command-line-interface, anylogic, non-interactive

I have some questions similar to [Managing multiple anylogic simulations within an experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634142/managing-multiple-anylogic-simulations-within-an-experiment), however in more detail:

We'd like to use AnyLogic simulation (especially Discrete Event Simulation) with a multi-node MonteCarlo approach, using variable parameter initializations. Each single simulation run should trigger a run of the jar file exported from our AnyLogic project. The overall experiment should be started by command line on Ubuntu Linux.

For this we need some non-interactive mode of the simulation in order to boost the performance as follows:

- The animation should not run in an experiment running on the command
  line.
- The simulation should run as fast as possible instead of
  real-time or proportional time lapse. E.g. when train ride A takes 5
  hours and train ride B takes 10 hours in reality, the simulation
  should not wait 5*C and 10*C seconds/hours/etc. It should be able to
  do such calculations immediately.

How can we achive this with AnyLogic?

Additionally, we also like to show the animations for a single simulation run, when a user provides concrete parameter values. For this, we could e.g. install AnyLogic on the Linux server or on a virtual machine running on top.

Thanks in advance

Luma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `getEngine().setRealTimeMode(false)` to run a simulation exp as fast as possible.

If you use a boolean parameter on main "timeMode", you can govern it from the command line input to decide if it should run as fast as possible or not.

Else, to turn off animation completely, the easiest way is to just use a ParameterVariation experiment, set it to run in "Freeform" mode with 1 iteration. This will boost your performance a lot.

Comment: Imho the simplest way to turn off animation is to run the simulation experiment and stay at the experiment canvas :)